# Calling a class method from a class with a has many relationship

Tags: ruby, methods, rails-activerecord

I have two classes, `A` and `B`.  B belongs to A and A has many Bs.

I want to call a method in A that affects multiple, but not necessarily all of the instances of B that belong to it.

I attempted to put the method in B and call it like this:

```
class A

    has_many :bs

    def method_to_update_many(array_of_the_many_attributes)
        array_of_the_many_attributes.each{ |n| self.bs.find_by(attribute:n).method_to_edit(update)
    end
end


class B

    belongs_to :a

    def method_to_edit(update)

    update_attribute(:attribute, update)

    end

   end
```

and by putting the method in A like this:

```
class A
    has_many :bs
    def update_a_b(b_identifier, update)
        the_b = self.bs.find_by(identifier: b_identifier)
        the_b.update_attribute(:attribute, update)
    end
end

class b
    belongs_to :a
end
```

It seems that everything I try fails because B is accessed through a CollectionProxy when called in relation to A.

Comment: Use simply `B.find_by`.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but `#find_by` is only going to return one record. You probably want to use `#where`

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understood but I think, you need to use `#where` and `#update_all` instead of `#find_by` and `#update_attribute`. Something like

```
self.bs.where(identifier: b_identifier).update_all(attribute: update)
```